# Laravel 6 Get information from POST JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, post

I'm trying to get JSON information from POST request. My POST request is:

```
var money = document.getElementById("code").value;
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='/paypal/';
Http.open("POST", url);
Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
Http.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: money
}));
```

And the controller is:

```
public function paypal(Request $r) {
$postInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postInput, true);
$response = array('value' => $data);
return Response::json($response);
}
```

but the only result that I get is:

```
{"value":null}
```

Any idea where is my problem?

Comment: If you do `console.log(money)` after var money, do you get `null` or the value you wanted?

Comment: I'm getting the value that I want.

Comment: can you check on your DevTools on Network tab, see if the payload is sent as JSON as you want?

Answer (score 0):

When using POST request dont forget to set csrf token in headers

add meta tag `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')          
var money = document.getElementById("code").value;
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = '/paypal';
Http.open("POST", url);
Http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
Http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token.content);
Http.send(JSON.stringify({value: money}));
```

To retrieve the JSON payload from your controller, use:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
return response()->json($data);
```

and make sure variable money have correct value

Comment: Okay, I'm sending the CSRF-Token now and tried your way to retrieve the JSON but again without success, I'm getting only `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. I fixed my issue by posting everything through GET request.

Answer (score -1):

For laravel, we can get POST JSON in an easier way.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function test(Request $request) {
    $inputData = $request->json()->all();
}
```